# Dynamics Crm 2013 customization breaks functionality add contact: "contact with id does not exist"

Tags: customization, dynamics-crm-2013, user-permissions

I added a custom field to CRM Contact and published customizations.

1. Logged on under my account
2. Changed prefix of Default Publisher from 'new' to 'xyz' (same prefix as publisher of consultant)
3. Added two fields to Contact entity under Settings/Customizations
4. Published all customizations

Since then, I cannot create a new Contact, neither from UI nor from unit test.

In the UI I get error 'The requested record was not found or you do not have sufficient permissions to view it', in the log and unit test exception I get 'contact With Id = 56edd2f7-469f-e511-80c0-00195d0a3a24 Does Not Exist'.

For the unit test I recreated the code using crmsvcutil.exe.

Comment: Even as administrator I get the same behaviour.

Comment: Do you have business rules which set lookup fields ?

Comment: No, business rules only show/hide fileds and set integer values

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add any plugin in pre-creation or validation? Looks like you are executing this plugin for both update and create, and stuff goes wrong in create because you are probably doing a retrieve operation on a record that still hasn't been created. Also the error that you get is the default if a record doesn't exist in crm (are you sure about that guid?). Try to open a new window with a contact, delete the contact from the main crm page, refresh the contact page, it should show that same error.